# Iptables rules for blocking range of ports

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a VM with OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu. I needed to block torrent traffic and I'm ok with some generic solution (not like someone will try to hack around). So I tried to block wide range of ports via Iptables. Biggest port I've seen in the list is 1194 (openvpn), so I wrote this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1195:65535 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 1195:65535 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1195:65535 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1195:65535 -j DROP
```

...and lost ssh connection immediately. Luckily I managed to recover and drop this rules

What went wrong? I didn't block ssh port, so what happened and how to fix this rules?

Comment: You might want to ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the following rule

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1195:65535 -j DROP
```

You have banned all the outward traffic, as a result the ssh daemon can not talk back to you

When you init an ssh connection you access the port 22, but the server assigns at random a port in the range 1024 - 65535 also called ephemeral ports, in order to communicate back at you